# For a binary classification algorithm, is there an objective way to know how large your set of positive and negative labels need to be?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, training, cross-validation, binary-classification

We're training a binary classification algorithm using a combined total of 2000 positive and negative labels that we purchased from a data vendor.

We mostly used all the textbook machine learning practices, such as K-fold cross-validation, and achieved a high F1-score.

Afterwards, however, we asked the data vendor to test our algorithm against 10000 further labels.  The results were not great.

Now, the next question is, do we purchase the additional 10000 labels from this vendor?  Or should we only purchase 5000, if that would be good enough?

Is there a way to know many more additional labels we would need to purchase?

Comment: Closely related [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/101863/64377). I'd suggest doing an ablation study on the existing data, this would give an indication about whether the performance would improve with more data.

Comment: @Erwan thanks!  I'll take a look.